# Partitions mounted with fstab, not opening from Nautilus nor Unity sidebars

Tags: unity, mount, nautilus, fstab

I had recently changed my partitions (reducing Windows partition to give more storage for Linux), and I used fstab to have convenient access to my file system.

I have not problem using these partitions from the command line, or by the symbolic links and rbinded mountings I created, when navigating with Nautilus.

However both Nautilus and Unity show entries in the sidebar for each partition, but I am not able to get to the respective partitions using them.  In the Nautilus sidebar I get an error: `mount: according to mtab, /mnt/bis is already mounted in /media/part mount failed`. In the Unity sidebar, I get no error, but nothing happens either.

My fstab looks like this:

```
UUID=c01f8baf-xxxxx /mnt/bis             ext4  nosuid,nodev,nofail                                                                               0 2
/mnt/bis            /media/part          auto  rbind,gid=1004,umask=0002,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Partition                                       0 0
/mnt/bis/myuser     /home/myuser/mydocs  auto  rbind,user,rw,nodev,noexec,auto,async,gid=1000,uid=1000,umask=0002,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Source 0 0
```

There is a similar configuration for the NTFS partition. Which reports the same problem.

[image: mount failed error message]

Note that the name on the Nautilus sidebar (as well as in the Unity sidebar) is the name given in fstab.

I have no problem double-clicking the `mydocs` folder from Nautilus in my home directory, nor navigating through `/media/part/` either through command line or by clicking folders in Nautilus.

I had posted a related question here: [Removable HDD defined in fstab causing problems at startup when not present](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553853/removable-hdd-defined-in-fstab-causing-problems-at-startup-when-not-present) (edited).

Comment: Once you mount a partition using `fstab` it will appear as a normal folder in Nautilus. You will not be able to access it from Nautilus or Unity sidebars. This is normal.

Comment: Then, they should not appear on the sidebars.  I know I can create a `.desktop` file to still get the desired folder from Unity sidebar, but the non-working icons should be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken, the format for you `/etc/fstab` is wrong.  The first entry is OK, but the next two should be similar.  You can always check it by entering the command `sudo mount -a`, which will mount all entries, but then you will see any errors at the commandline output.

Why would you even want to mount a partition to a mountpoint, then change that mountpoint to a different mountpoint?  That seems to be what you are trying to do.

It's much simpler, I think, to use symbolic links, and one mount command.  Once mounted, you can create a symbolic link from `/mnt/bis/myuser` to `/home/myuser/mydocs`  You can easily do this with Nautilus by creating the link in `/mnt/bis/myuser` after it's mounted, then moving it to `/home/myuser`, and renaming it to `mydocs`.  I actually use this method for all my home's data directories (Documents, Downloads, Pictures, etc).  It ends up looking like the normal directories, but can be shared with other OS's)

Comment: One of the reasons for mounting directories is that programs such as rsync treat differently symbolic links than mounted dirs.  I am testing on eliminating the double entries, though.

Comment: Okay, I left just one line for `/mnt/bis` with the `gid`, `umask` and `x-gvfs` parameters. Just by saving the `/etc/fstab` file it automatically fixed the entries in the sidebars of Unity and Nautilus.

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón:  Most apps, rsync included, have options for how to treat symbolic links. rsync has many options for symbolic links.  For me, it's an advantage, because I often want to skip them.  Anyway, I hope I at least helped solve your problems.