# Removable HDD defined in fstab causing problems at startup when not present

Tags: mount, external-hdd, fstab

Recently I made some edits in my fstab file after some change in my partitions. (check 
[Partitions mounted with fstab, not opening from Nautilus nor Unity sidebars](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553848/partitions-mounted-with-fstab-not-opening-from-nautilus-nor-unity-sidebars) ) In the process I wanted to include a removable device so it would be present for all users when it was present.

It automatically mounted as `\media\activeuser\HDDMaker` with user access permissions set to `activeuser` only.  My idea was to mount it as `\media\HDDMaker` with access permissions to any user in a given group (gid=1004 `common`).

The fstab file looks like this:

```
UUID=543Exxxxxx  /mnt/543Exxxxxx  ntfs-3g  rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,auto,gid=1004,umask=0002 0 0
/mnt/543Exxxxxx  /media/HDDMaker  auto     rbind,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=HDDMaker          0 0
```

This works fine when the HDD is attached to the computer at startup (except for the detail in my other question: [Partitions mounted with fstab, not opening from Nautilus nor Unity sidebars](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553848/partitions-mounted-with-fstab-not-opening-from-nautilus-nor-unity-sidebars) ), but when the HDD is not attached I have two problems.

1. It reports at startup that the device cannot be mounted. *(and the startup process is halted until you press `S`)*
2. When plug, after the system is up, it doesn't automatically mounts. You have to manually mount it as

   sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/HDDMaker

The desired behavior is that it reports no problem at startup, and that, when plugged, it automatically mounts on `/media/HDDMaker`, with permissions set to all users in group `common`.

Comment: I don't use removable disks permanently, so I'm not sure offhand how to do that, but your attempt is wrong.  The format is incorrect in `/etc/fstab`.  The first entry needs to be a block device, not a directory.  There should only be one single entry, mounting the partition to `/media/HDDMaker`, or whatever directory you want it to be.

Answer (score 5):

For an external drive, in order to prevent hold-up of the boot, the nobootwait option should be added to the fourth column in the /etc/fstab. Moreover, you should preferably [use the UUID](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID) of the drive instead to ensure the right drive is always mounted (and see @Marty Fried’s comment to your question) so you get:

```
UUID=XXXXX  /media/HDDMaker  auto     rbind,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=HDDMaker,nobootwait          0 0
```

[This post](http://techmonks.net/nofail-and-nobootwait-mount-options-in-fstab-prevent-boot-problems/) explains when and why this is a good method.

Furthermore, since fstab is run only on startup, unless you write a specific process to keep re-running it, you have to do a manual `sudo mount -a`
to mount the disk if added afterwards, if you use the fstab option to auto-mount.

Therefore, a solution you could try instead, if you have Desktop Ubuntu, is to eschew fstab for [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/271527/320999)

Comment: Nice post - short, informative, and to the point.  Plus, I didn't know about your "final solution".  I've never needed it, so far, but it's nice to know.  Maybe I can use it.

Comment: Does the `rbind` parameter be the appropriate here?